# For what orders does Cauchy's theorem hold?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

If a prime number $p$ divides the order of a finite group, then there is an element in $G$ of order $p$ — this is Cauchy's Theorem.

For what numbers $n$ does this hold? In other words:

> what is the set $C$ of positive integers $n$ such that every group with order divisible by $n$ has an element of order $n$?

If $n\in C$ and $G$ is a group of order $n$ then clearly $G$ is cyclic: it follows that $n$ is what is called a *cyclic* number, and this tells us that it is square-free and if $p_1\cdots p_r$ is its factorization into primes we have $p_i\not\equiv1\mod p_j$ for all choices of $i$ and $j$ in $\{1,\dots,n\}$.

On the other hand, it is not difficult to show that $C$ is closed under divisors: if $n\in C$ and $m\mid n$, then $m\in C$.

Finally, Cauchy's theorem tells us that $C$ contains all primes. Is there anything else in there?

Comment: Isn't it easy to construct counterexamples for all $n$ not of the forms you list?

Comment: But I don't have a list, really. Is there a non-prime element in $C$, apart from $1$ ?

Comment: If $n$ is exactly divisible by $p^r$, $r\ge2$, then $C_p\oplus \cdots\oplus C_p\oplus C_{n/p^r}$ should do. If $n$ is exactly divisible by $p^rq^s$ with $q\equiv1\bmod p$, then $G\oplus C_{n/p^rq^s}$ should do, where $G$ is a noncyclic group of order $p^rq^s$. What have I overlooked?

Comment: @gerry, indeed. In the body I mentioned that C is a divisor-closed set contained in the set of cyclic numbers, and your argument is what can be used to prove that it is contained in the set of cyclic numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your set $C$ contains only the primes (and 1).  Proof:  as you show, it's a divisor-closed subset of the cyclic numbers.  But $C$ does not contain any integer of the form $pq$ where $p < q$ are primes, because the group $S_q$ has order divisible by $pq$ but no elements of order $pq$.

Comment: Ah! Thanks! I knew I was missing an example like that.